# Assigning time-tied variable data to the previous minute's seconds in SAS

Tags: sas

I'm trying to figure out how to do the following in SAS. I have data taken by an NO2 sensor every minute. A GPS is recording a location at give or take every second. I need to assign the value of each data recording for every minute to the previous seconds of that past minute. The NO2 data recorded is an average of the previous minute.

Here's a sample of my data:  [Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvtmF.png)

I am looking to bring the data from the last line (NO2, Humidity, Temperature) "up" to seconds of the previous minute which have a GPS reading. The column is in `DateTime` format.

Would love any pointers on how to do this... Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please edit your question and post your sample data as text at the bottom.

Comment: What have you done in term of due diligence, @etienne-pelletier?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit unclear unfortunately. Assuming that you want to retrospectively assign NO2, Humidity and Temperature for all missing values within the last minute (60 seconds) you can do the following:

**Dummy data:**

```
data input ;
  format datetime datetime20. ; 
  datetime='28SEP2015:07:21:26'dt ;
    do i=1 to 120 ;
      datetime+1 ;
      if      i=80  then do ; no2=0.007 ; humidite=55.9 ; temperature=22.4 ; end ;
      else if i=120 then do ; no2=0.020 ; humidite=65.0 ; temperature=23.5 ; end ;
      else call missing(no2, humidite,temperature) ;
      output ;
    end ;
run ;
```

**Solution:**

Keep only the key records that contain values:

```
data key(rename=(datetime=keytime))  ;
  set input(where=(nmiss(no2,humidite,temperature) ne 3));
run ;
```

Run the key records over the original data as a hashtable:

```
data output(drop=rc rd i keytime)  ;
  *Load key table into memory ;
  if _n_=1 then do ;
    declare hash pt(dataset:"key",multidata:"yes",ordered:"yes");
    declare hiter iter('pt');
    rc=pt.defineKey('id');
    rc=pt.defineData('keytime','no2','humidite','temperature');
    rc=pt.defineDone();
  end ;

  *Read in original data ;
  set input ;
  rc=pt.find() ;

  *Update with key table values whenever needed ;
  if rc=0 then do ;
    rd=iter.first() ;
    if datetime gt keytime then rd=iter.next();
    if rd=0 and keytime-60 <= datetime <= keytime then output ;
    else do ;
      call missing(no2,humidite,temperature);
      output ;
    end;
  end ;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have two data sources.  One generates an observation every minute.  The other generates an observation as often as every second.  You want to join the two datasets together such that all of the frequently-sampled values for a within a given minute get the same occasionally-sampled value that corresponds to that minute.

Assuming that the NO2 samples really are every minute and have a timedate value of NO2_TD, and the GPS timedate stamp is "GPS_TD" [having a variable named the same as a function, informat, and format is generally a bad idea].  One of the best ways to join tables is through SQL.  Doing a FULL OUTER JOIN guarantees that if we have missing data on either side, we still get the observations from the other data source.

```
PROC SQL ;
  CREATE TABLE joined_data AS
    SELECT a.*, b.NO2_MSR, b.NO2_TD
      FROM gps_data a
           FULL OUTER JOIN
           no2_data b
             ON INTNX('DTMINUTE',a.GPS_TD,0,'B') EQ INTNX('DTMINUTE',b.NO2_DT,0,'B')
  ;
QUIT ;
```

Here we use INTNX to essentially ignore the seconds.  We shift the datetime values to a minute boundary (DTMINUTE), by 0 minutes, to the Beginning of the minute, essentially truncating the seconds for the purposes of the join.  INTNX is very commonly used to get the first of the month, last of the month, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need to do it back-fill the "time sorted" environmental data without regard to length of time between gps and environmental data sampling, then the following code pattern (based off Bendy's dummy data creation code) should be sufficient.

```
/* assuming input data is sorted by datetime value */
/* based on dummy data created with Bendy's code */ 
data fill_missing;
* read in the data but only keep the gps data - need to add lat and long to keep statement;
set input(keep=i datetime); 

if _n_=1 or datetime > datetime2 then do;
    drop datetime2; * drop the datetime value associated with the non-gps data ;
    * read only the rows that have the non-missing data using this set statement ;
    * and only keep the datetime (renamed to datetime2) and the non-gps data ;
    set input(keep=datetime no2 humidite temperature 
                rename=(datetime=datetime2)
                where=(no2 ne .));
end;
run;
```

Also note that this code pattern will stop outputting data when the datetime value of the input data exceeds the max datetime value associated with non-missing environmental data (non-gps). It sounds like this likely isn't a problem for your usage.